# element:last-child effects all the element and not only last

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Im trying to remove border-bottom from the last element, but it affect all the elements.

This is what I have for now.

HTML

```
 <div class="cv-content">
    </div>

    <div class="cv-content">
    </div>
```

CSS

```
 .cv-content{
    width:400px;
    float:left;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}       

.cv-content:last-child{
        border-bottom:0px solid #ccc;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FcCWG/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every `.cv-content` *is* the `:last-child` of `.cv-item`.  Use `.cv-item` instead:

```
.cv-item:last-child .cv-content {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FcCWG/1/

Comment: @MilchePatern I bet he figure it out from the jsFiddle.